# How to add Jest-React testing library to Expo

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, react-testing-library

I'm trying to install `Jest` and `React testing library` to my **expo project(sdk 47)**. While installing i'm getting dependency conflict. i'm new to testing can you please help me how to install

> Found: react@18.1.0 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!
> react@"18.1.0" from the root project npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0.0"
> from @testing-library/react-native@11.5.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@testing-library/react-native npm ERR!
> @testing-library/react-native@"*" from the root project npm ERR!   1
> more (react-native) npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-test-renderer@18.2.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-test-renderer npm ERR!
>
> react-test-renderer@"^18.1.0" from the root project npm ERR!   peer
> react-test-renderer@">=16.0.0" from
> @testing-library/react-native@11.5.0 npm ERR!
>
> node_modules/@testing-library/react-native npm ERR!
>
> @testing-library/react-native@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm
> ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm
> ERR! See C:\Users\rikvitha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt
> for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\rikvitha\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-22T05_28_56_533Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to install React testing library (RTL), or React-Native testing library (RNTL)? Your question say one thing, but your error logs the other, they are two distinct libraries. I am going to assume it's RNTL, because your also using expo.

The error log says that you have several dependencies that are in conflict with each other, i.e. you have a dependency conflict. What I would recommend is to remove the dependencies and add them again (if you have a commit where everything worked, you can do `git reset head --hard` to throw away your changes). I think your problem is with react-test-renderer, but dependency conflicts are tricky.
These are the versions I use:

```
"@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.1",
"@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.0",
"@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
"@types/react": "^18.0.21",
"@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
"@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
"babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
"react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
"ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
"typescript": "^4.9.4"
```

I use react-native (instead of expo) and typescript (instead of js), so there are a few more plugins that you probably don't need, unless your also using TS, but these versions should not conflict with each other.

Comment: Expo uses react 18.1.0 . So when is install test-renderer, or jest native, im getting dependency conflict because they require 18.2.0 react. Is there any way to install. Like installing older packages would work?

Comment: You can install specific versions using @ symbol, like `npm i react@18.2.0` or `react-test-renderer@18.2.0`